# Как объединить два CSS класса в один?

Tags: css

Есть огромная HTML таблица, решил сократить кол-во кода в ней.
Сейчас в не имеются теги с набором классов

```
<span class="badge badge-success">...</span>
<span class="badge badge-important">...</span>
```

Я же хочу сократить их до

```
<span class="bs">...</span>
<span class="bi">...</span>
```

Тупо копировать стили обоих классов в один новый не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 1):

Если хочешь, сокращай, а мой тебе совет вот так не делать

```
.badge badge-success, .bs{...}
.badge badge-important, .bi{...}
```

лучше вот так

```
.bs{...}    /* .badge badge-success */
.bi{...}    /* .badge badge-important */
```

объясняю, если вам имена классов слишком длинные, их можно подкоротить и оставить себе пометки в коде, чтоб понятнее было потом через пару лет, что где находится и к чему относится - вместо того, чтоб копировать классы.

если-же надо объеденить 2 класса в один, то этого достич можно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/5aKKR/49/)

Comment: @Brodobrey расширьте пожалуйста свой ответ, ничего не понятно.

Comment: глянь, теперь понятно?

Comment: По ссылке они у вас не объединены, а указаны оба. Объединить надо badge и badge-success в bs, badge и badge-important в bi.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите как во втором бутстрапе сделаны иконки:

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
    /* основные стили */
}

.icon-glass { background-position: 0 0;}
.icon-music { background-position: -24px 0; }
.icon-search { background-position: -48px 0; }
...
```

У вас, видимо, будет что-то вроде:

```
<style>
    [class^="badge-"],
    [class*=" badge-"] {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        heigh: 100px;
        /* и другие базовые стили */
    }
    .badge-success { backgroun-image: url(badge1.png); }
    .badge-important { backgroun-image: url(badge2.png); }
</style>

<body>
    <i class="badge-success"></i>
    <i class="badge-important"></i>
</body>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css

Может вы что-то типа этого хотите?

Но лично мне нравится вариант, который у вас изначально представлен. Да и бутстрап вот, к примеру, от таких хитростей обновился к варианту, как у вас опять же изначально. Так же ваш вариант хорошо описывается терминами [БЭМ](http://ru.bem.info/).

Если смотреть с другой стороны, то совсем не понятно, кто же выйграет от того, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Всем будет только хуже.

Comment: Таблица очень большая. Экономлю на чем могу, на пробелах, табах и названиях классов.

Comment: Тем более. Отказавшись проставлять базовый класс badge вам придется либо много много раз копировать этот базовый код каждому бейджу, либо делать более сложный селектор, более универсальный селектор (как иконки в бутстрап 2, как ребята вам раньше отвечали).

Comment: Я не хочу от него отказываться, мне надо отнаследоваться от них обоих. Селектор вообще не пойму чем мне может помочь.

Comment: Ну как же не хотите? :) Вот вы пишете, что было "badge badge-success", а стало "bs". Было два класса в селекторе, стал один :)

Comment: Я писать его не хочу, поэтому и пишу что надо объединить два класса в один.

Comment: В случае с вариантом "как иконки в бутстрап 2", вам не придется писать базовый класс.

Answer (score -1):

Можно например так поступить, только в итоге вы сократите код только за счёт названий классов.

```
.bs, bi {
    //общие стили
}

.bs {
    //конкретные стили
}

.bi {
    //конкретные стили
}
```

Comment: Мне надо объединить имеющиеся стили, а не создать новые. За счет длины названий и хочу.

Comment: Так что вам не понятно то? Очевидно, что в вашем случае в .bs, .bi { ... } копируйте стили из класса badge. В bs и bi копируй классы из badge-success и badge-important. Таким образом вы избавитесь от изначального класса badge, сократите названия классов, но сохраните стили.

Comment: Я же писал
>Тупо копировать стили обоих классов в один новый не хотелось бы.
Если в последствии кто захочет изменить badge-success и badge-important на всем сайте, мои стили им придется менять отдельно.